# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation with new FormData() through ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, twig, form-data

I have a form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit();">
...
</form>
```

On submit is called an ajax request:

```
data = $('#myForm').serialize();    
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'phpFile.php',
    data: data,
    response: 'text',
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
        $('#element').html(result['products']);
    }
})
```

The result in console log is:

```
{"ok":1,"products":"<span class=\"error\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\n<select id=\"productName\" name=\"productId\">\n        <option value=\"37\">osrieu<\/option>\n    <\/select>"}
```

So the key "products" in this json is a result of a Twig_Environment->render('htmlFile.html',['placeholder' => $variable]). In this case everything renders fine.

But the problems begins if i change the data variable to this:

```
data = new FormData($('#myForm'));
```

After this in the console log i get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
jQuery.param.add @ jquery.js:7499
buildParams @ jquery.js:7551
jQuery.param @ jquery.js:7519
jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8021
ajaxAdminPanelSubmit @ jsFile.js:66
onsubmit @ phpFile.php:84
```

Then a redirect to a blank page, and in the redirected page all i see is the same json:

```
{"ok":1,"products":"<span class=\"error\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\n<select id=\"productName\" name=\"productId\">\n        <option value=\"37\">osrieu<\/option>\n    <\/select>"}
```

My question is – why Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation occurs in this case?
Could this be fixed? And why it happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: In fact in both cases i get the correct $_POST and json in result. But if i set processData: false – $_POST is empty

Comment: your question is not clear also some variable try to post variable value  like you had posted data = new FormData(tmpData); what is tmpData ?

Comment: just go through it http://davidwalsh.name/fix-javascript-errors

Comment: Well, in my case it's 
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
I don't see this error in the list

Comment: Illegal invocation means that you are calling a function in the wrong context

Comment: can you post all your form elements

Comment: For me it's strange. I mean if i make only 1 change in this code – use $('#myForm').serialize(); instead of new FormData($('#myForm'));
all functions are in right context.
Uploaded the whole form i use.

Comment: As i see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects it works in a different manner

Comment: I use header Retrieving a FormData object from an HTML form from your link.